# Is re-asking a question with an accepted answer allowed, if that answer isn't the right answer any longer?

Tags: discussion, questions, reopened-questions

I asked a question before, and after a very long time and many updates, I solved it and was able to get past it.

However now the problem is back, and the original solution does not help in this case. What would be the best approach to reopen this question? Since it became community wiki, it has not seen action except by me, editing the question as I went on and finally answered the question.

It feels like unaccepting the answer and editing the question again would mean no one will really pay attention to it since it has 5 answers now, and it had 10 edits happen on it.

Is there a way I can ask this same question again? And does this mean that the solution to the question was wrong or just that something else went wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Definitely ask a new question, link the old.  A question should be a resource for others when it's complete, one specific, answerable question...and the accepted answer should have been *for that question*.

Things change, you now have a different question that needs answering...so do exactly that, ask a *new* question for your new problem, and both will later serve as specific resources with a viable answer.

---

Look at it from the other possibility: if you *did* edit the original, you'd have a bunch of out-of-context answers that don't fit the question, and it would be a poor/confusing resource for others finding it later.

Answer (score 5):

Ask a new question, referencing the old one and explaining why those answers won't work in the current situation.