# Should I unaccept the answer or make a new post of the same question?

Tags: discussion, questions

If I get confused again by the same question I asked before, should I unaccept the answer or ask a new question exactly duplicated?

Comment: Can you insert a link to the question?

Comment: Never ask a duplicate question. Perhaps consider a bounty instead to get renewed attention.

Comment: @KenKin  slugster asked for link to **the** question, not all your questions. Which of those are you referring to?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Given the "**If** I get confused", I'm assuming this is a hypothetical issue.

Comment: @Bart might be, but then why he gave link to his questions tab? Can't see any sense in this.

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14360593/what-should-the-method-findbaseclasswith-return)

Comment: Please don't be strict with me. I often found that I mis-expressed myself after long time later. I'm trying to correct this.

Comment: @KenKin I think you'll find this question helpful: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72429/is-re-asking-a-question-with-an-accepted-answer-allowed-if-that-answer-isnt-th

Comment: @Kate Gregory: Seems I should not accept an answer when the first time I thought its the most reasonable answer. I've asked a question and it's voted to close(not closed yet), so I think that I shouldn't ask an identical question because of I get confused again. According to the link, I realize it as `definitely ask a new question`, right? Hope that will not be a question flagged `duplicated`. Please leave an answer with more details, and I'd like to accept it. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the key to successfully asking a different question is going to be making it **different**. Say you first ask:

> how long does it take to drive from A to B?

And someone tells you "3 hours" and you accept it. Then later you learn that the route they are talking about involves using a different vehicle than the one you own, and you can't drive on that route.

At this point if you edit your question you will make all the answers invalid, so don't do that. But (**and this is really important**) don't just go open a new question and type:

> how long does it take to drive from A to B?

It will be closed as a duplicate. Give the question some time and thought. (I notice that you have a habit of editing comments and generally changing your mind that makes conversations hard to follow.) Ask your new question something like this:

> With [whatever vehicle you have] how long does it take to drive from A to B? I know that it takes 3 hours with [whatever the other answer assumed] but I don't have one of those and can't get one. So I can't take [that route] and will need to go a longer way. How long does that longer way take?

Even include a link to your older question. When you do this, you reduce the chances of being closed as a duplicate, because you're explaining what is different about this question and the other one.

Comment: @KenKin Please don't be so touchy on comments or answers directed to you as a person. All of them so far have been kind and helpful. They only serve to make the question or comment relevant to your immediate situation, while also being helpful to the general MSO audience. Don't worry about it. We're only here to help.

Comment: @Bart: In fact, I've never involed in any Q&A or forum before, even in my own country with my native language. I'm learning and practicing. I'd also like to share my personal knowledge to help others, if it would be helpful. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @KenKin Just don't worry so much. Keep your eyes open and you'll be just fine. ;)

Comment: @Bart: It's just hard to prevent my mis-expressing. And I tried to correct and correct again of my words.

Comment: [English was an unsafe language to me](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14078723/why-c-is-said-an-unsafe-language-while-c-sharp-is-a-safe-one-what-does-it-mea/14080289#14080289)

Comment: @KenKin your English is better than my grasp of your native language, I'm sure. But when you edit comments to say something totally different it can confuse people. You're learning, and we all support that. I am recommending that you wait to be sure before you post a question, answer, or comment, but I am not saying you're bad for how you've approached the site so far. You're learning.

Comment: @Kate Gregory: Thank you very much. I just think I do not `have a habit ..`; I considered that is I tried to correct what I expressed.

Answer (score 8):

If you are still confused by the **same** problem and if the accepted answer doesn't help then you should have never accepted it in the first place. However, if you are in this position, unaccept the answer and either edit the question to provide more information so you do get an answer that it truly helpful or consider posting a bounty.

However, if your edit would substantially alter the question or if your new problem is related, **but different** then post a new question linking back to the original and clearly explaining why it's different.

Comment: I removed previous comment. What I want to say is: Sometimes we might think the current answer is the answer; but we might find something strange later.

Comment: @KenKin - which is what I cover here. You have found **new** information which means the accepted answer doesn't help any more.